# How to enable a disabled sound card?

Tags: sound, 22.04, soundcard

A year ago, I disabled the internal sound card in order to only allow my bluetooth headset.

Now, I have changed my mind, but I have searched and searched, and I cannot find how I did it so that I can revert it. The only thing I remember is that it was a terminal command.

So how do I find the disabled sound card and enable it?

I might add that the command I ran made the sound card disappear completely from sound settings.

I tried running `pactl list cards` but I only found my bluetooth headset there.

I also ran `ls /dev/snd/by-id` but same result as above. Only my headset.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

I edited `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and commented out `blacklist snd_hda_intel` and rebooted.

To help people troubleshoot these things, what I did was a `history | grep snd` and I found something like this:

```
➜  ~ history | grep snd                        
 1727  lsmod | grep snd
 1728  lsmod | grep snd_hda
 9479  lsmod | grep snd
```

So then I did `history | head -n 1800 | tail -n 100` and looked what I did around that, and then I found this:

```
1723  sudo apt install pavucontrol
 1724  lsmod
 1725  lsmod | grep mic
 1726  lsmod | grep input
 1727  lsmod | grep snd
 1728  lsmod | grep snd_hda
 1729  cd /etc/modprobe.d
 1730  ls
 1731  cat blacklist-ath_pci.conf
 1732  vim blacklist.conf
 1733  sudo vim blacklist
 1734  sudo vim blacklist.conf
```

So I have obviously edited the blacklist file in the process of disabling the sound card.